# XML sitemap gets rejected by Webmasters tools

Tags: xml, sitemap

I read through similar issues but still not able to understand why this sitemap: http://www.sebastianprofessional.com/sitemap.xml gets

```
Errors
Invalid XML tag
This tag was not recognized. Please fix it and resubmit.
1
Parent tag: urlset
Tag: loc
Line: 682
```

AND

```
Errors
Missing XML tag
This required tag is missing. Please add it and resubmit.
1
Parent tag: url
Tag: loc
Line: 694
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance!
Alex

Comment: Please post the contents of the sitemap rather than a link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/jad3JTki - the content is too long to paste here.